# How can I exclude rows from a pandas dataframe depending on conditions across all columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df:

```
      population     plot1     plot2     plot3     plot4
0    Population1  Species1  Species1  Species2  Species2
1    Population2  Species4  Species2  Species3  Species4
2    Population3  Species1  Species2  Species1  Species2
3    Population4  Species4  Species4  Species4  Species4
4    Population5  Species2  Species2  Species4  Species2
5    Population6  Species4  Species3  Species3  Species4
6    Population7  Species3  Species4  Species1  Species3
7    Population8  Species4  Species4  Species4  Species4
8    Population9  Species3  Species4  Species2  Species3
9   Population10  Species1  Species3  Species2  Species4
10  Population11  Species2  Species4  Species2  Species4
```

I want to create a new dataframe with all rows (populations) in which Species4 occurs more than once are removed. I've tried several ways using *.value_counts()* but can't work out a way to apply it across the entire dataframe at once, rather than just by simply looping thru all rows (which takes a long time on the large dataset I have).

So, I tried:

```
dat.drop(dat.value_counts()['Species4'] > 1)
```

but *.value_counts()* cannot be applied to the entire df.

Answer (score 6):

Using `pandas.DataFrame.eq`:

```
new_df = df[df.eq('Species4').sum(1).le(1)]
# or
new_df = df[~df.eq('Species4').sum(1).gt(1)]
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
     population     plot1     plot2     plot3     plot4
0   Population1  Species1  Species1  Species2  Species2
2   Population3  Species1  Species2  Species1  Species2
4   Population5  Species2  Species2  Species4  Species2
6   Population7  Species3  Species4  Species1  Species3
8   Population9  Species3  Species4  Species2  Species3
9  Population10  Species1  Species3  Species2  Species4
```

Comment: Thanks how do I stipulate more than once (2 or more)?

Comment: @user3329732 Filtering _more than once_ is same as keeping _once or less_. I've updated another line that may read more nicely :)

Answer (score 1):

Use bool indexing like this for multiple condition indexing or any other combination of bool functions.

`df[((df == "Species4").sum(axis=1) > 1) & ((df == "Species1").sum(axis=1) > 1)]`